# Save and Read Expansion Files from data/data/

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I want to save expansion files on download directly on data/data(internal storage).Help will be appriciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.Your expansion files are downloaded in sdcard/Android/obb folder and you need to retrieve them and unzip it to use it further use
Here is some code to get Expansion files

private final static String EXP_PATH = "/Android/obb/";

```
static String[] getAPKExpansionFiles(Context ctx, int mainVersion,
        int patchVersion) {
    String packageName = ctx.getPackageName();
    Vector<String> ret = new Vector<String>();
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        // Build the full path to the app's expansion files
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File expPath = new File(root.toString() + EXP_PATH + packageName);

        // Check that expansion file path exists
        if (expPath.exists()) {
            if (mainVersion > 0) {
                String strMainPath = expPath + File.separator + "main."
                        + mainVersion + "." + packageName + ".obb";
                File main = new File(strMainPath);
                if (main.isFile()) {
                    ret.add(strMainPath);
                }
            }
            if (patchVersion > 0) {
                String strPatchPath = expPath + File.separator + "patch."
                        + mainVersion + "." + packageName + ".obb";
                File main = new File(strPatchPath);
                if (main.isFile()) {
                    ret.add(strPatchPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    String[] retArray = new String[ret.size()];
    ret.toArray(retArray);
    return retArray;
}



String[] test = getAPKExpansionFiles(myContext, 2, 0);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "total file : " + test.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "filename is : " + test[i]);
        if (test.length > 0) {
            try {
                file = APKExpansionSupport.getResourceZipFile(test)
                        .getAllEntries();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "total zip file : " + file.length);
                for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {

                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "zip filename is : "
                                + (file[i].mFileName).split("/")[1]);

                        File("/mnt/sdcard/Android/obb/one.example.expansion.downloader/main.3.one.example.expansion.downloader.obb/myvideo.mp4");
                        File desc = new File("/mnt/sdcard/.YourFolder");

                        ZipHelper.unzip(test[0], desc);


                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Good Luck !

Comment: actually expansion files do not provide security to data. Because data on sdcard so any one can access it which break the authentication rules

Comment: Yes @Goofy how can I help you?

Comment: Yes @Goofy you can invite me

Comment: @SanketPandya can you join here  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5098/android-people and ping me?

Comment: @SanketPandya can you please join there?